calculate bearing and distance between two UTM points - different zones
i'm trying to create a flight simulator. in that flight simulator I want to make my plane fly itself, meaning i want it to know it's current location, next location, and time he's flown and calculate his next position.
i'm using UTM coordinates, as i have straight lines on the map (calculation using lat-lon always takes into account the earth's curvature and produces spherical straight lines, but not 2D straight lines - which is what i need).
here are my calculations at the moment:
def calculate_azimuth(self, other): #self is current location, other is next
    delta_easting = other.easting - self.easting
    delta_northing = other.northing - self.northing

    azimuth_rad = math.atan2(delta_easting, delta_northing)
    azimuth_deg = math.degrees(azimuth_rad)

    return (azimuth_deg + 360) % 360

def calculate_new_location(self, azimuth, distance):
    # Calculate new easting and northing
    azimuth_rad = math.radians(azimuth)
    self.easting += distance * math.sin(azimuth_rad)
    self.northing += distance * math.cos(azimuth_rad)

this works fine except for when the two points are in different zones (and of course it does, i am not taking into account the zones in my calculations).
for example, going from here:
281198E/3657016N/37S (which is 33.02968259091583, 36.657254305140704 in lat,lon)
to this location:
420893E/3834016N/36S (which is 34.645019557370496, 32.13682341152369 in lat,lon)
produces this azimuth:38.281
any idea how to take into account the different zone nums while remaining in UTM?
moving to lat-lon in all ways or directions failed me. i need the flight path to be a straight line on a 2D map. conversion to lat-long fails this.
